# Shiny server error: No UI defined

Tags: shiny-server

When I open my shiny application on shiny server, I got an error:

```
No UI defined

Shiny couldn't find any UI for this application. We looked in:

www/index.html
ui.R
```

I have checked:

- The shiny server is running
- I can run the default hello application.
- I can run my local application without problem.
- I have run the same application before on my shiny server and it worked. However it is not working with the same codes.
- All file under my application have -rw-r--r-- permission.

Can anybody help me with this? Why did it happened?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did get same kind of error but it was because I forgot to save the changes made in ui.R file. It runs last saved version of ui.R.

Hope you are not making the same mistake.